# error starting vmware workstation 12 on kali linux

Tags: linux, kali-linux, gcc, vmware

When I try to run vmware workstation 12, I'm greeted with the following message. I've tried the following:

- pointing the location to /usr/bin/gcc
- apt-get install libglib2.0-0
- apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`
- apt-get install --reinstall gcc

Any help that can be provided would be much appreciated :) Thanks in advance!

[image: error]

Comment: Please post the outputs of `whereis gcc` and `gcc -v`

Comment: Try to install gcc++ : apt-get install gcc++

Comment: http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/forum/install-vmware-workstation-vmware-player-kali-linux-2-0-0164083/ Never tried, but seems to work.

Comment: whereis gcc:
gcc: /usr/bin/gcc /usr/lib/gcc

gcc -v:
gcc version 6.1.1 20160802 (Debian 6.1.1-11)

Thx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Answer (score 0):

`VMware` is explicitly asking for `gcc-5.4.0` while the version on your system is `gcc-6.1.1`. The requested version may be in the repository and should be installable in parallel with the more recent version (note that I am not sure that such a version is indeed available).

Otherwise you have to upgrade `VMware` to a more recent version that was compiled with `gcc-6.1.1` **or** you have to find `gcc-5.4.0` for kali from other sources.

Answer (score 0):

> Upgrade Kali to the Latest Which is 4.8.0-kali1-amd64

```
cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source

tar xf vmmon.tar

tar xf vmnet.tar

cd vmmon-only

make

cd ../vmnet

make

cd ..

mkdir /lib/modules/`uname -r`/misc

cp vmmon.o /lib/modules/`uname -r`/misc/vmmon.ko

cp vmnet.o /lib/modules/`uname -r`/misc/vmnet.ko

depmod -a

/etc/init.d/vmware restart
```

> Everytime there's a New build for Kali. You have to go through the
>   steps again.